# Problemas con background video en Storyboard en Xamarin iOS (no en Xamarin Forms)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

Necesito insertar un video background de mi aplicación (Login).

Estoy usando este código en el método ViewDidLoad

```
            MPMoviePlayerController mpPlayer;
            mpPlayer = new MPMoviePlayerController (NSUrl.FromFilename 
                                        ("imagenes/login/video_login.mp4"));

            mpPlayer.ControlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None;
            mpPlayer.ScalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.AspectFill;
            mpPlayer.ControlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None;

            fondoLogin.Add (mpPlayer.View);
            //fondoLogin.AddSubview (mpPlayer.View);

            mpPlayer.View.Frame = new CGRect (0, 0, View.Frame.Width,View.Frame.Height);

            mpPlayer.SourceType = MPMovieSourceType.Streaming;
            mpPlayer.SetFullscreen (true, true);
            mpPlayer.PrepareToPlay ();
            mpPlayer.ShouldAutoplay = true;
            videoEndNotificationToken = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver
                                                            (AVPlayerItem.DidPlayToEndTimeNotification, VideoDidFinishPlaying, mpPlayer);
            mpPlayer.RepeatMode = MPMovieRepeatMode.One;
            mpPlayer.Play ();
```

No muestra el video que puse en la carpeta de recursos de mi proyecto. El video tiene formato mp4

PD: Estoy construyendo sobre iOS 11 y quiero que mi inicio de sesión se vea como el de Spotify.